# How can i Show a bitmap on screen

Tags: android

i want to display a bimap pattern on screen.Now suppose i want to display a rectangle of red color on screen but i dont know how a bitmap data looks for a rectangle.
Please give some example of it..

Comment: Do you want to display a bitmap on the screen or do you want to modify a bitmap with a red rectangle and display that on the screen?

Comment: I want to draw a bitmap image on screen...like a rectangle of red color using android API,s

Comment: show ur expected output as screenshot.

Comment: @Androider: I want to show a rectangle of red color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a xml called **pattern.xml** in drawable folder with source as Red picture like below:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/redpicture" 
        android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

Then Create a layout like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/pattern">
</LinearLayout>
```